# Data insertion not happening in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert data into a database. the connection is working fine. However I can't insert data and I have no idea why. The table is just not getting updated.

```
string ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Kaushalya\\Documents\\NewAgain.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Tabel1(name) VALUES (@UserName);",conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", Convert.ToInt32(0)));
```

Connection when tested is working fine. However, I can't do anything with the database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute the Command object.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

More info [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson03.aspx).

Comment: thank you. How do i insert values from a textbox. i used ur tutorial and it adds values to the DB. I give the commands as values('TextBox1.Text.ToString()') and it adds precisely that and not the value in the textbox1.

Comment: @GeeKaush use a parameter to add the value, just as you did above

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `ExecuteNonQuery()` to run the query.